# Is it possible to change the position of text in a richtextbox? and how?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, styling

Is it possible to change the position of text in a richtextbox? and how? I want to offset the text from the top and left of the box to create a margin with coloured background around the text.

Comment: colored background around `text` or `richTextBox`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place the `richTextBox` in a colored `Panel` as `Dock.Fill` and adjust the `Panel's Padding` to your needs